# Given $\epsilon > 0$, show that the unit disc contains finitely many dyadic squares whose total area exceeds $\pi - \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, circles, epsilon-delta

I found this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676868/show-that-finitely-many-disjoint-discs-can-be-inscribed-in-a-unit-square-with-to). The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907405/unit-disc-contains-finitely-many-dyadic-squares-whose-total-area-exceeds-pi?rq=1) is obviously not the answer I need. The question is:

> Given $\epsilon > 0$, show that the unit disc contains finitely many dyadic squares whose total area exceeds $\pi - \epsilon$, and which intersect each other only along their boundaries.

I tried to solve it but a misunderstanding still remains.

**My solution:**

First I put the center of disc at the origin of Cartesian coordinates. Then I tile the number plane with dyadic squares each of side length $2^{-n}$. Now I need to come up with a formula that gives "**an upper bound** for the total area inside the disc that is *not covered by a square* and *lies entirely within the disc*". I came up with the formula by chatting with a friend online:

> ***His key insight:*** The greatest possible distance between any two points in small square is its hypotenuse which is $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}$
>
> Therefore draw a concentric circle of radius $1-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}$ inside the unit disc. **Then any point on any square that "lies both inside and outside the disc" will always be outside the inner concentric circle**.

Then it can be easily shown that the area between two concentric circles is:

$$\dfrac{2 \sqrt{2}}{2^n}- \dfrac{2 \pi}{2^{2n}}$$

This is "**an upper bound** for the total area inside the disc that is *not covered by a square* and *lies entirely within the disc*". This also is a decreasing function of $n$ whose limit goes to zero when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Thus the total area "inside the disc that is *not covered by a square* and *lies entirely within the disc*" goes to zero when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Thus the result of theorem follows.

**My confusion:**

Why is the bold sentence in "***His key insight***" true?

Comment: You can write out everything in a set theoretic fashion; I guess that should help; you can write $B(0,1):= \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ to denote the ball with the interior with radius $1$, maybe that will convince you

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a square with side length $2^{-n}$ that “lies both inside and outside the disc.” Then there is a point $a \in S$ with $\Vert a\Vert > 1$.

For all $b \in S$ is (using the triangle inequality)
$$
 \Vert b \Vert  = \Vert a - (a-b)\Vert 
\ge \underbrace{\Vert a \Vert}_{> 1} 
- \underbrace{\Vert a-b\Vert}_{\le \sqrt 2/2^n}
 > 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^n}
$$
and that proves that $S$ is outside the inner circle.